# Inspect install_requires from a python package

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to debug installing a package on a machine which has an old version of `pip`; for reasons I don't want to get into, upgrading pip to a more recent version is not an option. The error message I get is:

```
# pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
# python -m pip install grpcio
Downloading/unpacking grpcio
  Downloading grpcio-1.21.1.tar.gz (13.9MB): 13.9MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/grpcio/setup.py) egg_info for package grpcio
    Found cython-generated files...
    error in grpcio setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Found cython-generated files...
error in grpcio setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
```

I've tried looking at the [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/) and the [Github page](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/python/grpcio) for the package, but neither appears to have an explicit `install_requires` file available. Pip does not seem to have a means to display this either. Is there a way I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how far this generalizes, but after getting more detailed logs of the error, I found that it was downloading a `.tar.gz` from https://pypi.org/simple/grpcio/

So if other people have the problem, `https://pypi.org/simple/`packagename`/`version`.tar.gz` is a good place to try.